# Transfer files with limited number of connections and with Camel SFTP

Tags: java, performance, apache-camel, sftp, jbossfuse

We have a requirement where we need to download more than 100k files and upload them to a different FTP server(EFT) with maximum of 10 connections allowed to connect to destination server. As number of files are huge to download, we are using 3 threads to run in parallel but observing lot of fall outs as destination allows max of 10 connections. I observed Camel SFTP have options of disconnect, soTimeout. Just wondering what's the correct way to go and is it ok from performance perspective  disconnecting for each file and creating new connection again? Is it recommend to go with single threaded instead of concurrent processing. Any help is appreciated.

```
//Sample route
from("sftp://username@source/data?password=password")
.log()
.to("sftp://username@source/data?password=password&disconnect=true&soTimeout=120000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your problem, I might suggest one way. Instead of doing download and upload in same route, better separate both in two different route. 
Say,

1. Use first route to download file from FTP and place it in your
   local folder somewhere.
2. Use second route to read that local
   folder path and copy file to FTP and then delete those file from
   local.

Hope this might help.